# Adding too many animated meshes to the scene in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

For a game project I need approximately 1000 animated stickmans on the scene. Stickmans will be in clusters similar to image i shared. I’ll use single and basic stickman model and single running animation. Only colors of the stickmans will be different.
I think I need to optimize these using instanced skinned mesh but i’m confused about the process and its feasibilty.
I also wonder if there is a way to calculate the vertex-geometry change on animation.
The following image can be a reference.

I tried to use threejs instanced mesh but it didn't work with skinnedmeshes.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBFHZ.jpg)